# How to fix multiple values of Access-Control-Allow-Origin in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-gateway

I have a Spring Cloud Gateway Version 2.6.8 with this Configuration

```
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@Configuration
public class GatewayWebSecurity {
  private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GatewayWebSecurity.class);

  @Value("${allowed.client.host}")
  private String allowedClientHost; //--->this is http://localhost:4200

  @Bean
  public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
    http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource()).and().csrf().disable();
    return http.build();
  }

  @Bean
  public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList(allowedClientHost));  //--->this is http://localhost:4200
    configuration.setAllowedMethods(List.of("GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "POST", "OPTIONS"));
    configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
  }
}
```

Let say my allowedClientHost is configured as http://localhost:4200/. When I do requests, I got this Error Message in Chrome.

> ...from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple
> values 'http://localhost:4200, http://localhost:4200', but only one is
> allowed

I dont have any other CORS Configis. When I replace in this class host with "*" like,

```
configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("*"));
```

The error message changes to

> The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values
> '*, *', but only one is
> allowed

I tracked this code with Debugger, it runs only 1xTime over this Method. I cant explain why the value lands twice there. I also doublechecked this in chrome devtools.

[image]

What I do wrong here?

## Update

After hours and hours of debuging, I found the cause of the problem.
This is a new bug introduced with Spring Boot 2.6.8 and Spring Cloud v2021.0.3. Revert of Dependencie Update Commit back to 2.6.6 with 2021.0.1 instantly resolved the Problem. I will try to create a minimal reproducable code and open a new issue on gitgub.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that having

```
http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource())

//and

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource()
```

register it twice. Either remove `configurationSource` or `@Bean`

Comment: I removed @ Bean of corsConfigurationSource. Still same bug

Comment: Tried the other way around?

Comment: Yes, also same.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change the .htaccess file. You need write the below code.

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews -Indexes
</IfModule>
```

Here sometime it causes due to server issue.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved similar issue by removing CORS configurations from upstream applications that are connected to the spring gateway